# Create url for JSON file

Tags: reactjs, json

I am currently learning JSON. How can I generate/make a url that I can use to `fetch` in `useEffect` in react? For example I have my `data.json` file here

```
[
    {
        "name": "CBD Infused Gummy 40mg (2400mg 60ct Bottle)",
        "category": "Edibles",
        "sub-category": "Energy",
        "description": "RedBear Energy Gummy Bears are powered by caffeine and vitamin B12, This is the perfect snack to get you through that meeting that should have been an email.",
        "price": "50.00",
        "id": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "CBD Infused Gummy 40mg (2400mg 60ct Bottle)",
        "category": "Edibles",
        "sub-category": "Energy",
        "description": "RedBear Energy Gummy Bears are powered by caffeine and vitamin B12, This is the perfect snack to get you through that meeting that should have been an email.",
        "price": "50.00",
        "id": 1
    },
```

Comment: Where is this JSON file in relation to the code consuming it? If this is a local asset file you can either just import it directly like any file. What have you tried? See [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese yes it's in my local asset file. I can retrieve the data but I can't do POST method

Comment: Uh, your question seemed to be about GETting a JSON file... what exactly are you trying to do? You need a server with endpoints if you want to make POST requests.

Comment: @DrewReese yeah that's what I mean, my bad

Comment: I need the url in order for me to perform the CRUD in react. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to make a local strapi build. Takes less then 5 minutes. You can make an API that you can consume locally. You can also deploy this API remotely.

[https://strapi.io/](https://strapi.io/%20can%20make%20an%20API%20that%20you%20can%20consume%20locally)